# unslider carousel or infinite do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I have a blog  and I want to use an unslider script to make carousel and infinite slideshow such that the slideshow have such action (good situation is my wish):

```
slide1 slide2 slide3 slide4 slide5 slide6 slide7 slide8 slide1 slide2 ...
```

But slider currently (at the moment) action is:

```
slide1 slide2 slide3 slide4 slide5 slide6 slide7 slide8 ...doesn't continue to slide1 (dire situation)
```

It also  jumps to slide one (the start point).

The problem I have is that when slider arrives to last slide it jumps to first slide and starting all actions from the first.

Working with unslider is very hard but I think unslider has not infinite or carousel option to use.

Please visit my blog to see problem.

[ardatradecenter.rozblog.com](http://www.ardatradecenter.rozblog.com)

Problem in bottom in brands holder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same Problem here, The issue comes from version compatibility.
Please refer to the Git. 
https://github.com/idiot/unslider/issues/218